# How to copy the title of the item checked in the list view to the clipboard

Tags: sharepoint-online

The following code was added to the list view with the ScriptEditor. It works on Chrome but does not work with Edge. The version of Edge corresponds to Promise, Async, Await.

```
<script language='javaScript' type='text/javascript'>
var getSelectedItems = function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject){
        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var listId= SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

        var list= context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
        var currentItem = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[0].id));
        context.load(currentItem,'Title');
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){
                resolve(currentItem);
            },
            function(){
                reject(args.get_message());
            }
        );
    })
}

async function exec(){
    await getSelectedItems().then(function (items){
         var copyFrom = document.createElement('textarea');
        copyFrom.value = items.get_item('Title');
        document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
        copyFrom.focus();
        copyFrom.select();
        var retVal=document.execCommand('copy');
        if(retVal){
            alert('Success');
        } else{
            alert('Fail');
        }
        copyFrom.parentElement.removeChild(copyFrom);
    }).catch(function(error){
        alert(error);
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="TitleCopy" onclick="exec();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
<script language='javaScript' type='text/javascript'>
function exec(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var listId= SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
        var list= context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
        var currentItem = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[0].id));
        context.load(currentItem,'Title');
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){
                var copyFrom = document.createElement('textarea');
                copyFrom.value = currentItem.get_item('Title');
                document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
                copyFrom.focus();
                copyFrom.select();
                var retVal=document.execCommand('copy');
                if(retVal){
                    alert('Success');
                } else{
                    alert('Fail');
                }
                copyFrom.parentElement.removeChild(copyFrom);
            },
            function(){
                console.log(args.get_message());
            }
        );  
    }, "sp.js");     
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="TitleCopy" onclick="exec();" />
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply. However, when it was corrected and executed, "Fail" was displayed.

Comment: I modify the code, you can check it, if still get errors, I suggest you provide the error messages for further research.